# Create a msbuild for multiple files

Tags: c#, compilation, msbuild, config

I wrote a file for compile multiples files but it is not work.

`<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Compile">
    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesToCompile Include="hola.cs"/>
        <FilesToCompile Include="hola2.cs"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>

        <AssemblyName>Proyecto</AssemblyName>
        <OutputPath>Bin\</OutputPath>

        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="Compile">
        <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputDir)"/>
        <Csc Sources="@(FilesToCompile)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName)" Optimize="$(Optimize)" TargetType="exe" />
    </Target>
</Project>`

It show me this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWyof.png)

In English:

> error CS0017: Program 'output file name' has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

Comment: Can you get an English version of that error an post it as text, not an image?

Comment: Sure @dangerzone, error CS0017: Program 'output file name' has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by my myself.

```
<Project DefaultTargets = "Compile" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >
<PropertyGroup>
<NombreClase1>hola1</NombreClase1>
<NombreClase2>hola2</NombreClase2>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Clase1 Include = "hola.cs"/>               
<Clase2 Include = "hola2.cs"/>              
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name = "Compile">            
<CSC Sources = "@(Clase1)" OutputAssembly = "$(NombreClase1).exe">            
<Output TaskParameter = "OutputAssembly" ItemName = "Ejecutable1" />                        
</CSC>        
<Message Text="Archivo compilado @(Ejecutable1)"/>          
<CSC Sources = "@(Clase1)" OutputAssembly = "$(NombreClase2).exe">
<Output TaskParameter = "OutputAssembly" ItemName = "Ejecutable2" />                    
</CSC>
<Message Text="Archivo compilado @(Ejecutable2)"/>      
</Target>                       
</Project>
```